# C# Xamarin OnClick function

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

What I'm doing is this

```
Button button1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);

button1.SetOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // Perform action on click
        }
    });
```

but for some reasons I'm getting `OnClickListener` underlined with red. and I can't do anything to launch a function when I click my button .

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `Xamarin.Android` way of doing a `SetOnClickListener` is via C# style events:

```
Button button1 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
button1.Click += (sender, e) => {
   // Perform action on click
};
```

Required reading for Xamarin's Android [Events and Listeners](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/api_design/#Events_and_Listeners)

Answer (score 4):

The real issue here is in your `SetOnClickListener` you are setting an inline **anonymous class** implementing `OnClickListener` interface.

This is not supported in C#, From the [C# programming guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), you can find,

> Anonymous types are class types that consist of one or more public read-only properties. No other kinds of class members such as methods or events are allowed. An anonymous type cannot be cast to any interface or type except for object.

But it doesn't mean that you cannot use `SetOnClickListener` at all.

You can either do `button1.SetOnClickListener(this)` and implement your `OnClickListener` in the same class

or

create a class (can be inner class) implements `OnClickListener` with your implementation and pass an it's instance to your `SetOnClickListener`

In both ways, your are obeying C#'s "Real Name Policy" :)

Answer (score 4):

No need of using either delegates or c# style events, you can use both depending on the class being used. Remember that the View.IOnclicklistener is an interface so inherit from it like so,

```
public class myactivity : AppcompatActivity, View.IonClickListener
```

It prompts you to implement the onclick method of the interface like below,,

```
public void OnClick(View v)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

You can use a mixture of c# style events and event listeners. What java can do Xamarin can do
..This is the correct answer to this question i believe..