# How to set onclick listener in xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm quite new to C# and Xamarin and have been trying to implement a bottom sheet element and don't know how to correctly do it. I am using [Cocosw.BottomSheet-Xamarin.Android](https://github.com/fabionuno/Cocosw.BottomSheet-Xamarin.Android) library.

Here is my code:

```
Cocosw.BottomSheetActions.BottomSheet.Builder b = new Cocosw.BottomSheetActions.BottomSheet.Builder (this);
b.Title ("New");
b.Sheet (Resource.Layout.menu_bottom_sheet)
```

Now i think i should use `b.Listener(...)`, but it requires an interface `IDialogInterfaceOnClickListener` as a paramater and i don't know how to do it in C# correctly.

In Java i could write

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Perform action on click
    }
});
```

I tried doing this:

```
class BottomSheetActions : IDialogInterfaceOnClickListener {
    public void OnClick (IDialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Console.WriteLine ("Hello fox");
    }

    public IntPtr Handle { get; }

    public void Dispose() {

    }
}
```

and then this:

```
b.Listener (new BottomSheetActions());
```

But it didnt work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The simplest way is indeed using the `Click` event that's available on every View. However, in order to implement `IOnClickListener` (or any other interface that's also an `IJavaObject`) you need to make the class implementing it inherit from [`Java.Lang.Object`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Java.Lang.Object/):

```
internal class BottomSheetActions : Java.Lang.Object, IDialogInterfaceOnClickListener 
{
    public void OnClick (IDialogInterface dialog, int which)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Hello fox");
    }
}
```

This way you don't need to implement `IntPtr Handle` and your code will work just fine

Comment: I am working with a third party library, which requires `IDialogInterfaceOnClickListener`, so i can't use `Click` event, but i might try inheriting from `Java.Lang.Object`, thanks.

Answer (score 25):

Use click event instead.

```
button.Click += delegate 
{
    //Your code
};
```

See my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35104981/5718968) for more info

Comment: this doesn't work the same as setOnClickListener function. Using the event as shown in your code causes certain issues such as overlapping events 

The setOnClickListener is a more stable option.