# Force instances to implement a method

Tags: c#, instance

It's possible to enforce derived classes to implement an specific function.

Now, is it possible to do the same for each instance of the class separately? (probably when calling the constructor like Java on-the-fly override)

```
// on-the-fly override sample @Java
progressBar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
});
```

p.s: There is only ONE class that I want to create an instance for it. No sub-classes in this case.

Comment: What do you mean by "Is it possible to do the same for each instance of the class?" instance can't implement anything, the class is implementing methods/functions.

Comment: its possible to do something like this in java, for events

Comment: you can try to work with delegates, leave only constructor accepting that delegate

Comment: If you want every *instance* of your class implement your method in a different way, you may use a delegate and provide it within the constructor.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, this is not the same. It is not a duplicate of that question. The java feature is on-the-fly override, which is not directly supported by c#.

Comment: Related `SetOnClickListener` issue (in Xamarin C#): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35104531/c-sharp-xamarin-onclick-function. Note that inline anonymous class implementing `OnClickListener` which used in the Java example doesn't supported in C#, the possible workaround is using `SetOnClickListener(this)` and implement `OnClickListener` in same class; or use built-in event feature like `ProgressBar.Click += (sender, e) => { ... }`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, I have double-checked, Damien_The_Unbeliever did that. sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instances can´t implement an interfaces, only classes can. Also in Java that´s not possible. Instead an anonymous class is created in the back that derives from your base-class, which appears as an instance of your base-class.

To achieve something similar in C# you could use a delegate and provide it within the cosntructor of your class:

```
class MyClass
{
    Action<T> TheAction { get; private set; }
    public MyClass(Action<T> doSomething() { this.TheAction = doSomething; }
}
```

Now you can provide different behaviour *per instance*:

```
var i1 = new MyClass(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
var i2 = new MyClass(x => DoSomething(x));
```

However I don´t see why you even need this. To enable a click-event for a progressbar simply do the following:

```
myProgressBar.Click += (sender, args) => { /* what ever */ };
```

or:

```
myProgressBar.Click += MyMethod;
```

with

```
MyMethod(object sender, EventArgs args) { /* what ever */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Interfaces` can be used to require all derived objects to implement their methods ([see this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface)). From the sounds of this though, `base.Method()` is more of what you're looking for ([see this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/base)):

```
internal class A {
    public virtual void DoSomething() { }
}
internal class B : A {
    public override void DoSomething() { base.DoSomething(); }
}
```

The above is useful for ensuring the code within `A.DoSomething` is executed when `B.DoSomething` is called.

Using an `interface` is the only way I know to force derived objects to implement methods.

Comment: You don´t have an interface, but a base-class with a virtual method, which yiou don´t even *have* to override. "Using an interface is the only way I know to force derived objects to implement methods" No, there are abstract classes also.

Comment: Read the post more thoroughly. I didn't demonstrate `interface` implementation, only how `base` works. Also, the phrase you quoted there; I clearly state it is the only way I know. NOT the only way available.